# Combine RxJS Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

**Problem**: I need to route to the login page if firebase-auth does not have a user signed in and to an alternate page if it does have a user logged in.

To achieve this it would invoke a function in a constructor service.

```
private isLoginRequired() {
// Firebase auth service observable
let authSub = this.afAuth.authState;

// Current route service observable
let routeSub = this.activatedRoute.url;

//Alternate App Page
//this.router.navigate(["tool/event-management/events"]);

//Login Page
//this.router.navigate(["tool/event-management/login"]);

}
```

Now, I need to combine these observables in such a way that **if a value of any one of them changes I could collect current values of both the observables via single subscribe.**

```
something.subscribe(observableSnapshots => {
  let snapshot_auth = observableSnapshots[0];
  let snapshot_route = observableSnapshots[1];

  if(condition<snapshot_route, snapshot_auth>){
    // do anything positive
  }
  else{
    // do anything negative
  }
});
```

I understand that this can be achieved by nesting the subscriptions but that's surely not an efficient way to do it.

I have also tried mergeMap but could not achieve the requirement, here is the snippet (which does not work)

```
routeSub
      .pipe(mergeMap(event1 => authSub.pipe(map(event2 => "test"))))
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result);
      });
```

Please show me a better way out. Thanks in advance.

> **Dependency**: "rxjs": "~6.3.3"

Comment: You shouldn’t subscribe to your inner obs but to your outer..

Comment: @MikeOne I have tried swapping them around wasn't helping much.

Comment: Have you looked into router guards in Angular? They can handle the auth logic before the user lands on the page.

Comment: @sketchthat, What if the user is already on the page, and event to lock that page(such as logout) is triggered from a second tab?

Comment: @AbhijitSrivastava if the user is already on the route and you want to hide elements if they are not authenticated, I suggest you have a method on a service which returns the `authState` observable to the component - in your template use `*ngIf` on elements you want to hide, and inside the `*ngIf` subscribe to the `authState` observable using the `async` pipe. If the user is authenticated the elements will show, if not it will be `null`.

Comment: @nclarx, I do not want to hide elements if they are not authenticated, rather throw him on the login page. Furthermore,  I would hold myself back to add extra code to hide complete HTML if not authenticated. And in the case where authentication is an async API call that would be a pain.

Comment: @AbhijitSrivastava then the best way to do this is a route guard, see my answer below, but you need to subscribe to the authState object in the component and write an `if` to route them to login if the authState becomes null. I'll update my answer

Comment: Here is an article that shows a visualization of ways you can merge observables in Angular.  Its worth a look.  [Learn to combine RxJs sequences with super intuitive interactive diagrams](https://blog.angularindepth.com/learn-to-combine-rxjs-sequences-with-super-intuitive-interactive-diagrams-20fce8e6511)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I arrived at this code snippet with the help @Drenai response.

```
private isLoginRequired():void {
let authSub: Observable<firebase.User> = this.afAuth.authState;
let routeSub: Observable<any> = this.router.events;

combineLatest(authSub, routeSub).subscribe(
  ([authSubSnap, routeSubSnap]):void => {
    let islogin: boolean = !!authSubSnap;
    let current_url: string = routeSubSnap.url;

    if (!islogin) {
      this.router.navigate([this.loginPageURL]);
    } else if (current_url === this.loginPageURL && islogin) {
      this.router.navigate(["tool/event-management/events"]);
    }
  }
);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use a **route guard** to do what you are describing:

This is a slightly modified code snippet from Jeff Delaney's AngularFirebase website, see: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/google-user-auth-with-firestore-custom-data/:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { tap, map, take } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router)
{}


  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {

      return this.auth.authState.pipe()
           take(1),
           map(user => !!user),
           tap(loggedIn => {
             if (!loggedIn) {
               console.log('access denied')
               this.router.navigate(['/login']);
             }
         })
    )
  }
}
```

Here is how to add the guard to the router:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '**', component: SomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
]
```

You can import the Firebase `auth` observable in the guard as I have done here, however, it is better practice to have it in its own service imo. Check the link to AngularFirebase to see the code for a service that does this.

If you want to throw the user out of a route if they are logged out, try the following code in your component:

```
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
        constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router)
{
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.auth.authState.subscribe((authObj) => {
            if(authObj === null){
                this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're doing, but it sounds like `combineLatest` might work

```
// Firebase auth service observable
let authSub = this.afAuth.authState;

// Current route service observable
let routeSub = this.activatedRoute.url;

const sub = combineLatest(authSub, routeSub)
   .pipe(
     tap(([authResult, routeResult]) => {
         // the above uses array param destructuring, so we have two variables
         if(authResult === something and routeResult === something){
            //Do Something
         } 
         else {
           // do something else
         }
     })
   )
   .subscribe();
```

The `activatedRoute.url` is an [observable of a `BehaviorSubject`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router_state.ts#L69) so it will give you the latest result when you subscribe, and I presume the Firebase Auth service will so the same, but you'll have to test it out

There may be syntax errors in this, just typed it directly, but it's your basic `combineLatest`

- Article on array parameter [destructuring from 2ality](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html#pitfall-destructuring-a-single-arrow-function-parameter)
- Docs for [rxjs combineLatest](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest)

Comment: Be aware that combineLatest will not emit an initial value until each observable emits at least one value.

Comment: activatedRoute.url is an observable of a BehaviorSubject so it will give you the latest result "Once" and thus above code did not go in subscribe(). This was a surprise for me so I change a code to 
 combineLatest(this.afAuth.authState, this.router.events).subscribe() and is working perfectly fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This will probably get hit many many times, as router.events fires dozens of events. You could add in a `pipe( filter())` to only process the events you're interested in with something like `filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)`. You're params will be different, but same idea